# Filtered, large list exporting

Tags: export, large-lists, indexed-column, export-to-excel

I'm currently managing a large list (just over 5000 items) and have a filtered view using indexed columns that is returning 143 items.  I want to export those 143 to Excel.  I'm getting an error saying that I "...don't have permission to view the entire list because it is larger than the list view threshold..."

When I export other (smaller) lists with filtered views it only exports the results of the filter, not the whole list.  I had some counts on the list that I removed, there's no grouping.  What am I missing?